# Inserting an element in a specific id based on a data attribute

Tags: javascript

I am trying to dynamically insert elements within a loop, in to the corresponding DIVs based on the dataset values. Basically if the two elements have matching dataset value, it should be inserted in to a specific div.

The dataset values are unique, however in some cases the dataset values can appear more than once.

I have used the following code in another part of the project I'm working on, however I can't seem to make it work with the next thing I need to do.

```
var callingPointsWrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".callingstations");
                                var currentCallingWrapper = [...callingPointsWrapper].find((wrapper) => wrapper.dataset.callingpointsid === trainUID);
                                var callingWrapperFragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(callingPointsTemplate);

                                // add to correct element
                                callingPointsWrapper.appendChild(callingPointsTemplate);
```

All my code is shown below in context. Thanks in advance.

```js
// scripts

// change protocol to https if http
if (window.location.protocol != 'https:') window.location.protocol = 'https';

// 
var info = document.querySelector(".info");

// check if geolocation works/is supported using if statement
// if geolocation is supported
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {

    // log to console
    console.log("GeoLocation is working.");

    // function to run if geolocation is supported
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

        // store users coords
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;

        // log them to console
        console.log("Your coordinates are: " + lat + "," + lon);

        // callback function to use users coordinates in another function
        findNearestStation(lat, lon);

    });

    // if geolocation is not supported
} else {

    // log to console
    console.log("GeoLocation is not supported.");
}

// empty array for timetable information
var serviceUrlArray = [];

function findNearestStation(lat, lon) {

    // log to console
    // console.log("Your coordinates are: " + lat + "," + lon);

    // api keys and tokens
    var appID = "xxx";
    var appKey = "xxxxxx";

    // api for nearest stations url template
    var transportApiUrl = "https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/stations/near.json?app_id=" + appID + "&app_key=" + appKey + "&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&rpp=5";

    // ajax request to get nearest stations
    var nearbyStationsReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    nearbyStationsReq.open('GET', transportApiUrl, true);

    nearbyStationsReq.onload = function() {

        // results window
        var resultsWindow = document.querySelector(".results-window");

        // empty array for the timetable urls
        var timetableUrlArray = [];

        // empty array for station codes
        var stationCodeArray = [];

        // clear the results window
        resultsWindow.innerHTML = "";

        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            // response data
            var res = JSON.parse(this.response);

            // variable for stations array in response
            var data = res.stations;

            // for loop to iterate through response data
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                // get information from response data
                var code = data[i].station_code;
                var name = data[i].name;
                var distanceMetres = data[i].distance;
                var distanceKilometres = (distanceMetres / 1000).toFixed(1);
                var distanceKilometres = distanceKilometres + "km";

                // log data to console to reference
                // console.log("Code: " + code + " | Name: " + name + " | Distance: " + distanceKilometres);

                // generate urls for timetable data
                var timetableUrl = "https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/station/" + code + "/live.json?app_id=" + appID + "&app_key=" + appKey + "&darwin=true&train_status=passenger";

                // push completed urls to the array
                timetableUrlArray.push(timetableUrl);

                // push codes to empty array
                stationCodeArray.push(code);

                // template for nearest stations result container
                var resultTemplate =
                    "<div class='result'>" +
                    "<div class='station-name'>" +
                    "<span class='service-origin'>" +
                    "<span class='nr-logo'>" +
                    "<img src='assets/images/nr.svg' alt='National Rail Logo'></span>" + name + "</span>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class='service-results-wrapper' data-stationcode='" + code + "'></div>" +
                    "</div>";

                // insert template in to the results window
                resultsWindow.innerHTML += resultTemplate;

            }

            // log to console
            // console.log(stationCodeArray)

            // for loop to create a request for each station
            for (var i = 0; i < timetableUrlArray.length; i++) {

                // ajax request for timetable request
                var timetableReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                timetableReq.open('GET', timetableUrlArray[i], true);

                timetableReq.onload = function() {
                    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
                        // response from request
                        var res = JSON.parse(this.response);

                        // data for timetable info
                        var data = res.departures.all;

                        // declare service results wrapper
                        var serviceResultsWrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".service-results-wrapper");

                        // loop to go through the data
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                            // information required
                            var currentStation = res.station_name;
                            var currentStationCode = res.station_code;
                            var aimedDepartTime = data[i].aimed_departure_time;
                            var expectedDepartTime = data[i].expected_departure_time;
                            var destination = data[i].destination_name;
                            var platform = data[i].platform;
                            var operator = data[i].operator_name;
                            var status = data[i].status;
                            var trainUID = data[i].train_uid;

                            // generate url
                            var serviceURL = "https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/service/train_uid:" + trainUID + "///timetable.json?app_id=" + appID + "&app_key=" + appKey + "&darwin=true&live=true"

                            // log data to console
                            console.log("Current Station: " + currentStation + " | Current Station Code: " + currentStationCode + " | Aimed: " + aimedDepartTime + " | Expected: " + expectedDepartTime + " | Destination: " + destination + " | Platform: " + platform + " | Status: " + status + " | Operator: " + operator + " | ID: " + trainUID + " | URL: " + serviceURL);

                            // if platform is null
                            if (platform === null) {
                                // change variable to string
                                var platform = "n/a";
                            }

                            // switch statement to change styling based on status
                            switch (status) {
                                case "EARLY":
                                    var status = '<span class="status ontime">On time</span>';
                                    break;
                                case "ON TIME":
                                    var status = '<span class="status ontime">On time</span>';
                                    break;
                                case "LATE":
                                    var status = '<span class="status delayed">Delayed' + " " + expectedDepartTime + '</span>';
                                    var aimedDepartTime = '<span class="time unavailable strikethrough">' + aimedDepartTime + '</span>';
                                    break;
                                case "CANCELLED":
                                    var status = '<span class="status cancelled">Cancelled</span>';
                                    break;
                                case "NO REPORT":
                                    var status = '<span class="status unavailable">Unavailable</span>';
                                    break;
                                case "STARTS HERE":
                                    var status = '<span class="status ontime">On time</span>';
                                    break;
                                case "OFF ROUTE":
                                    var status = '<span class="status unavailable">Unavailable</span>';
                                    break;
                                case "CHANGE OF ORIGIN":
                                    var status = '<span class="status unavailable">Unavailable</span>';
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    var status = '<span class="status unavailable">Unavailable</span>';
                            }

                            // template for service boxes
                            var serviceBoxTemplate = "<span class='service-box' data-station='" + currentStationCode + "' data-uid='" + trainUID + "'><span class='service-time-status'><span class='service-depart-time'>" + aimedDepartTime + "</span>" +
                                status +
                                "<span class='service-depart-platform'>Plat. <span class='service-platform-number'>" + platform + "</span></span></span>" +
                                "<span class='service-destination'><span class='service-destination-name'>" + destination + "</span></span>" +
                                "<span class='callingstations' data-callingpointsid='" + trainUID + "'>Leigh-on-Sea, Chalkwell, Westcliff, Southend Central, Southend East, Thorpe Bay, Shoeburyness</span>" +
                                "<span class='service-operator'>Operated by <span class='service-operator-by'>" + operator + "</span></div>";

                            // inserts correct service in to correct station element based on matching codes
                            var currentWrapper = [...serviceResultsWrapper].find((wrapper) => wrapper.dataset.stationcode === currentStationCode);
                            var serviceBoxFragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(serviceBoxTemplate);

                            // add to correct element
                            currentWrapper.appendChild(serviceBoxFragment);

                            // ajax request to get service info
                            var serviceReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            serviceReq.open('GET', serviceURL, true);

                            serviceReq.onload = function() {
                                if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {

                                    // response text
                                    var res = JSON.parse(this.response);

                                    // get array within response text
                                    var data = res.stops;

                                    // get the trains UID
                                    var trainUID = res.train_uid;
                                    // var currentStation = res.station_name;

                                    // new array for calling points
                                    var callingPointsArray = [];

                                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                                        // get the calling points station names
                                        var callingPoint = data[i].station_name;

                                        // push names in to an array
                                        callingPointsArray.push(callingPoint);

                                        // create a string and add a comma between each name
                                        var callingPointStr = callingPointsArray.join(", ");

                                        // split the array where the calling 
                                        var subsequentCallingPoints = callingPointStr.split(currentStation);

                                        var callingPointsTemplate = "<span>" + subsequentCallingPoints + "</span>";

                                        subsequentCallingPoints[1].substring(1).trim()

                                    }

                                    var callingPointsWrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".callingstations");
                                    var currentCallingWrapper = [...callingPointsWrapper].find((wrapper) => wrapper.dataset.callingpointsid === trainUID);
                                    var callingWrapperFragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(callingPointsTemplate);

                                    // add to correct element
                                    callingPointsWrapper.appendChild(callingPointsTemplate);
                                    // // add to correct element
                                    // currentWrapper.appendChild(callingPointsFragment);

                                    // callingPointsWrapper[0].innerHTML = "";
                                    // callingPointsWrapper[0].innerHTML = subsequentCallingPoints[1].substring(1).trim();


                                    // console.log(callingPointsArray)

                                } else {
                                    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

                                }
                            };

                            serviceReq.onerror = function() {
                                // There was a connection error of some sort
                            };

                            serviceReq.send();
















                        }
                        // console.log(serviceUrlArray)



                    } else {
                        // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

                    }
                };

                timetableReq.onerror = function() {
                    // There was a connection error of some sort
                };

                timetableReq.send();



            }


        } else {
            // log to console
            console.log("There is an error.");

        }
    };

    nearbyStationsReq.onerror = function() {

        // log to console
        console.log("There is an error.");

    };

    nearbyStationsReq.send();

}
// var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

// request.onload = function() {
//   if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
//     // Success!
//     var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
//   } else {
//     // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

//   }
// };

// request.onerror = function() {
//   // There was a connection error of some sort
// };

// request.send();



// x
```